# Power surge on hub when using NooElec nesdr mini

Tags: rtl-sdr

I'm trying to set up sdrSharp on my PC using a NooElec nesdr mini for the receiver.  I've read a bunch of setup instructions which all suggest using [Zadig](http://zadig.akeo.ie/) to install the usb drivers for the receiver.

However, whenever I plug the nesdr into my usb port I receive an error `Power Surge on Hub` after which my computer disconnects the port which means I can't install the drivers for that device.

Has anyone run into this?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have a defective device with an internal short or other flaw causing it to draw too much current.

The RTL dongles are fairly high power (note how warm they get), but should be well under the 500 mA USB current limit; I run two of them from a single bus-powered hub. (I measured the draw of some a while ago, but I don't have records on on that handy.)

Obtain a replacement or second dongle (lots of uses for them anyway!) and test it. If the second one doesn't fail, then you probably got a defective unit. If it does, you evidently have a particularly picky USB port.